# Wrong character encoding in ssh session – but not for all connectios

Tags: ssh, encoding, character-encoding

I have an odd issue when connecting to my (Ubuntu) server via SSH.

If I connect from my Gentoo box, all is fine. All Umlauts etc. work, I can type "ÄÖÜ" and so on.

If I do the same from my Artix box, typing Umlauts doesn't yield anything in the shell, and e.g. typing them in a vim session leads to garbage output (e.g. "�~D�~V�~" is the output for "ÄÖÜ").

Both machines run KDE and use OpenRC, both have locales configured in the same way:

`/etc/locale.gen` contains `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8`, the locale is also set to this, and on both machines, I get the following output (also on the Ubuntu server!):

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Interestingly, this also happen when doing an "indirect" SSH connection: When I connect to the Artix box from the Gentoo box, everything still works as expected (typing Umlauts etc.). When I connect to the server from within this session, the result is the same as if I connected directly from the Artix machine.

Oddly enough, if I create an SSH connection from the Artix machine to the Gentoo machine, the Umlaut stuff works … but not if I connect to the Ubuntu server.

What causes this?

Comment: Can you verify what `env | grep -E "^LANG|^LC"` and `locale charmap`, as well as `locale -a` show in all those situations?

Comment: Also, can you verify what `sudo cat /proc/$PPID/environ | tr \\0 \\n | grep -E "^LANG|^LC"` shows _locally_ in your terminal (Konsole) on Artix?

Comment: `env | grep -E "^LANG|^LC"` shows `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` on Gentoo, Artix, and if I connect from Gentoo to Ubuntu. If I connect from Artix to Ubuntu, I get no output.

Comment: `locale charmap` shows ''UTF-8` on Gentoo, Artix and if I connect from Gentoo to Ubuntu. If I connect from Artix to Ubuntu, I get `ANSI_X3.4-1968`.

Comment: `locale -a` shows a lengthy list including `de_DE.UTF-8` on the Ubuntu server, and a shorter list on the other machines. But all include `de_DE.UTF-8`.

Comment: And here's the output of `sudo cat /proc/$PPID/environ | tr \\0 \\n | grep -E "^LANG|^LC"` run locally (through a VNC session, so it should be the same result as if I sat in front of the machine) run on Artix:

`LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de`

Comment: You've got an answer that is based mostly on one of your comments. The answerer did best to help you, still the current situation is sub-optimal because this is not how the site is designed to work. To fix this, please [edit] the question and add all the relevant information *there*. The point is to let future users with similar problems get the whole picture by reading the question alone. If they think this matches their problem then they will go to the answer. Do not require them to read comments, make the question standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `env | grep -E "^LANG|^LC"` shows `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` on Gentoo, Artix, and if I connect from Gentoo to Ubuntu. If I connect from Artix to Ubuntu, I get no output.

This most likely means that:

1. The Ubuntu server's PAM configuration doesn't read /etc/default/locale upon login or the file doesn't define `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` like it should, therefore your SSH logins actually rely on the locale-related environment variables being forwarded by the SSH client; **and**
2. Your SSH client on Artix is not configured to forward the locale-related environment variables either, i.e. it doesn't have the typical `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in `ssh_config`.

Preferably you should fix #1 first – set the Ubuntu server's system locale, using `localectl set-locale` if it has that, or possibly `dpkg-reconfigure locales` in the Debian way. This will help not only SSH sessions but also system services (e.g. when they write to system logs and in other situations).

(Note that for #1, not all distros work identically – Ubuntu uses pam_env, while Arch instead sets the environment variables through /etc/profile, which adds even more complications.)

Comment: I ran `dpkg-reconfigure locales` on the server, but it already was configured. `de_DE.UTF-8` was already selected to be generated, and it was also selected as the default locale. Also, `/etc/default/locale` already contained `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`. No change in the behavior … I'll try to tweak `ssh_config` …

Comment: I now added `SendEnv LANG LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LANGUAGE LC_ADDRESS LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_NAME LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (taken from my Gentoo configuration) and that made it work. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Update: The Ubuntu not appying the locale was caused by `UsePAM no` set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I disabled this to only allow public key auth. Actually, this can also be achieved by setting `PasswordAuthentication no` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`. With `UsePAM` set to `yes`, the locale is applied correctly, even without `SendEnv`.

Comment: Yeah, `UsePAM no` was very much the wrong way to go about it. For one, PAM deals with more than just authentication (even during pubkey auth – it still handles account expiry, it handles session setup as you just found out); while at the same time disabling PAM doesn't even guarantee that password auth would be disabled because sshd can also verify passwords directly against /etc/shadow, old-style.